# Can Glade make a GtkPopoverMenu?

Tags: gtk, glade

I can add things like a GtkButton to GtkPopoverMenu in Glade, but how to add menu items? Is it possible in Glade, or do I have to do it programmatically?

[image]

Generated Glade code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.40.0 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">440</property>
    <property name="default-height">250</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkMenuButton" id="menubutton1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="focus-on-click">False</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">end</property>
            <property name="valign">start</property>
            <property name="popover">popovermenu1</property>
            <child>
              <placeholder/>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
  <object class="GtkPopoverMenu" id="popovermenu1">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="relative-to">menubutton1</property>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

The thing I am trying to achieve:

[image]